# Two presentations of a group, one certainly finite. Need the other be?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I know the answer to the question above is "no", quite flatly. The counter example is below:

$$\mathbb{Z}\cong\langle a,b\mid b^2a^{-1}\rangle\cong \langle a,b\mid\lbrace b^{2^{n+1
}}a^{-2^n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace\rangle.$$

> So my question, more broadly, is that if $\langle A|R\rangle\cong\langle A|R'\rangle$ and we know that $R$ is finite, what can we say about $R'$?

I think we can say that $\langle R\rangle^N\cong \langle R'\rangle^N$, viewed inside the free group on $A$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can say that all but finitely many of the relators in $R'$ are redundant - i.e. they follow from the others. You haven't said what $N$ is and I don't know what you mean by "viewed inside the free group on $A$".

Comment: $\langle R\rangle^N$ is notation for the normal subgroup generated by $R$, and I'm remarking that this is occurring in the free group on the alphabet $A$ as $\langle A|R\rangle:=F(A)/\langle R\rangle^N$.

Comment: I don't like that notation! It looks like the normal closure of $\langle R \rangle$ under some subgroup $N$. I prefer $\langle\langle R \rangle\rangle$. Anyway, the answer is yes, $\langle\langle R \rangle\rangle \cong \langle\langle R' \rangle\rangle$, becuase they are free groups whose rank is determined by $|\langle A \mid R \rangle|$.

Comment: Although $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle\cong\langle\langle R'\rangle\rangle$, it is obvious that there are examples where $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle\neq \langle\langle R'\rangle\rangle$ (for example, $\langle a, b\mid a\rangle\cong\langle a, b\mid b\rangle$). What is perhaps less obvious is that there are examples where the subgroups $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ and $\langle\langle R'\rangle\rangle$ lie in different automorphic orbits of the ambient free group (and, surprisingly, in these examples you can take $R$ and $R'$ to consist of a single element).

Comment: @DerekHolt I've been thinking about the claim you made, that there is a reduction of $R'$. I believe it goes as follows: Since $\langle\langle R \rangle\rangle \cong \langle\langle R' \rangle\rangle$ by some $\phi$, we find that $\langle\langle R' \rangle\rangle \cong \langle\langle \phi(R) \rangle\rangle$. But, since $R$ is finite, $\phi(R)$ is a collection of conjugates of some finite set $\lbrace r_i\rbrace\subset R'$. So, in fact, $\langle\langle R' \rangle\rangle=\langle\langle \lbrace r_i\rbrace \rangle\rangle$ as desired.

Comment: Yes that argument works!